# Kadane's Algorithm not returning correct value for largest consecutive sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, kadanes-algorithm

Trying to use Kadane's Algorithm as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OexQs_cYgAQ&t=721s

On this array of numbers: `[-5, 10, 2, -3, 5, 8, -20]`.

The answer is `10 + 2 – 3 + 5 + 8 = 22`

---

However when I run the following code I get this:

`sumArray = [ 0, 20, 24, 24, 28, 44, 44 ]`

No idea how `24` and higher numbers gets in there :( and `22` is missing.

Code below:

```
const myArray = [-5, 10, 2, -3, 5, 8, -20];

const findMaxConsecutiveSum = (arr) => {
  const sumArray = [];
  let max_so_far = 0;
  let max_ending_here = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    max_ending_here = max_ending_here + arr[i];
    // console.log('position:', i, arr[i]);
    // console.log(max_ending_here = max_ending_here + arr[i]);
    // console.log('max_ending_here', max_ending_here);

    if (max_ending_here < 0) {
      max_ending_here = 0;
    }
    else if (max_so_far < max_ending_here) {
      max_so_far = max_ending_here;
    }

    // console.log('max_so_far', max_so_far);
    sumArray.push(max_so_far);
  }

  return sumArray;
}

console.log(findMaxConsecutiveSum(myArray));
```

The idea is I just fill up sumArray then filter it by the largest number.
However I don't get `22` and instead a ton of larger numbers?

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the implementation a lot more complicated than it needs to be. From the post on [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm), the code should look something like the following:

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = A[0]
    for x in A[1:]:
        max_ending_here = max(x, max_ending_here + x)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

The algorithm as stated there wants a *single number* to be returned, not an array. Translated to JS, that would look like:

```js
const myArray = [-5, 10, 2, -3, 5, 8, -20];
const findMaxConsecutiveSum = (arr) => {
  let max_so_far = 0;
  let max_ending_here = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    max_ending_here = Math.max(arr[i], max_ending_here + arr[i]);
    max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
  }
  return max_so_far;
}
console.log(findMaxConsecutiveSum(myArray));
```

Note that the reassignment of `max_ending_here` requires calling `Math.max` on `arr[i]` and `max_ending_here + arr[i]`.

Comment: Thanks, the part I was missing was `Math.max`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand Kadane's algorithm (from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm) post), the way to implement it is something like this:

```js
const myArray = [-5, 10, 2, -3, 5, 8, -20];
console.log(myArray.reduce((t, v) => { t.here = Math.max(v, v + t.here);
                                       t.max = Math.max(t.max, t.here); 
                                       return t; },
                           { here : 0, max : 0})['max']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I know there was a way to use `reduce` to do it :)